# Cordova IOS Project: Platforms folder missing

Tags: ios, cordova, upgrade, phonegap-build

I am trying to upgrade an old Cordova IOS project and unfortunately the Platforms directory went missing. Now I didn't find a way to upgrade it to latest IOS Cordova version as I need the `www`folder which sits inside the pltaforms directory. Any suggestions on how to deal at this condition to upgrade my project? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/pz4WCGehNDw

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, somehow the folders `platform` and `plugins` where placed a level above my project folder. So if your folder is `c:/projects/ionic-project` changes are that the folders are located in `c:/projects`